# xlsxwriter.exceptions.InvalidWorksheetName Excel worksheet name must be <= 31 chars

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

While creating excel output in python , length of the file is > 31 . Is there any way we can handle this issue...?

```
xlsxwriter.exceptions.InvalidWorksheetName: Excel worksheet name  must be <= 31 chars.
```

If this is a duplicate question please let me know. Because i am unable to find exact solution

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not with `xlsxwriter` (see [here](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/exceptions.html)).

What you can do is: generate a file with a shorter file name and rename it after creation:

```
import os

os.rename('a.xlsx', 'this_is_a_very_long_file_name_with_more_characters_than_32.xlsx')
```

Comment: Question is about sheet name "Excel worksheet name  must be <= 31 chars" not about file name